# preg_match: /usersname or /username/foo

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm wanting to preg_match the following URIs. Note usernames are: [\w]{1,15}

```
/username
/username/foo
/usersname/bar
```

I want these to fail

```
/username/anythingelse
```

The username is mandatory, so the preg_match should work if just a username is given, and then check if anything after is  either `foo` or `bar`.

```
preg_match('{^\/([\w]+){1,15}/{/foo|/bar}?$}', $uriString)
```

You can probably tell my preg_match fails. How may I fix this?

Comment: Too much curly brackets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses to specify a group of alternatives;

Curly braces are only used to limit repetition `{min,max}`

`^\/\w{1,15}(\/foo|\/bar)?$`  ==> [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/lB5dT2/1)

Above, we allow `\w` 1 up to 15 times (`\w` matches any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_])

Followed by either `\/foo` or `\/bar`

`^` and `$` specify the start and the end of the string, meaning that the regex must match the full string not only a part of it

You can read more about:

- [Limiting Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
- [Parentheses for Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)
- [String Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)